# Can't create a Non-Deterministic functions in MySQL with binlog_format=ROW (or MIXED)

Tags: mysql, database-replication, stored-functions, mysqlbinlog

In MySQL 8.0, even with binlog_format set to "ROW" or "MIXED" I seem to be unable to create a non-deterministic function. e.g:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION nonDeterministicFunc()
    RETURNS CHAR(4)
BEGIN
    RETURN LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0xffff)), 4, '0');
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

gives the error:

> ERROR 1418 (HY000): This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL,
> or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled
> (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators
> variable)

I'm aware that during replication, if binlog_format is set to STATEMENT then the slave DB will re-call the function and get a different result, but I thought when set to "ROW" or "MIXED" it would replicate the row changes not the function calls and so non-deterministic functions were fine?

The comment from MySQL support Margaret Fisher seems to say this is a feature:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101480#c511192

> "This ensures that if the binary logging format changes after the function is created, it will still work."

I understand the danger that someone changes the replication format later.... but surely that is an extreme corner case and that adding non-deterministic functions should to be allowed when replication is currently set to ROW or MIXED?

Or am I completely missing the obvious?

Comment: *Can't create a Non-Deterministic functions* None tells to MySQL does this function is deterministic or not. MySQL tells you that you must specify this simply.

Answer (score 1):

Any session may override the `binlog_format`, so the MySQL Server cannot rely on the global setting to ensure that the function is safe. If the function's code performs an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, and the session has been changed to `binlog_format=STATEMENT`, it would cause a different change on the replica than on the source.

I recommend you add the `NO SQL` option to your function definition to satisfy the error check.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bill. This is a shame - does this mean that any non-deterministic work (that includes INSERT etc, my example was intentionally simplified) must be done in the application code rather than in SQL stored procs?  Also a simple version number increment (e.g. UPDATE x SET ver=ver+1 WHERE...) in a trigger, can that be marked as DETERMINISTIC (assuming all the calls happen in the same order)?

Comment: Yes, you would need to define stored procedures using one of the options mentioned in the error message, or else refrain from using stored procedures. TBH, I hardly ever use stored procedures in MySQL anyway.

Comment: Surely if I mark this function as NO SQL that still doesn't make it deterministic (actually, CREATE PROC statement syntax seems to indicate as much) and so any statement which calls it will become non-deterministic as its calling a non-deterministic function? Or will it store the results of the statement in the calling statement....? The possible issues are endless....

Comment: Alternatively, you could set `log_bin_trust_function_creators=ON` which is also mentioned in the error message. Then you assume responsibility for making sure your routines don't cause replication problems. But if you are deploying your database to a shared hosting environment, you might not have the privilege to change that global variable.

Comment: The enforcement of deterministic functions is clearly pretty half-assed. They trust you, the developer, to mark your functions and procedures accurately, and they don't actually have any way of enforcing it. Ultimately, it's your responsibility and it's in your own interest to not make routines that cause damage to your replicas.

Comment: Thanks Bill, sorry, final question....  if we are set to ROWS, will this definitely only pass the actual row changes.... i.e. non deterministic functions cant cause issues?

Comment: Yes, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html: _On the replica side, only the row changes are seen, not the stored program invocation._